# Show text cursor for readonly inputs in WebKit

Tags: css, webkit, html-input

```
<input value="Default" />
<input readonly value="Readonly" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EBQ3U/

In Firefox, clicking on the disabled input field reveals a non-blinking text cursor. I like this behavior because it tells the user that they can use Ctrl-A to select the input's contents. Chrome doesn't give any such visual indication. How can I change that without making the input field writable?

Comment: that's a reported issue waiting to be resolved - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167142

Comment: Thanks for the link. Guess I'll just have to wait, then.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code with CSS -->
HTML

```
<input value="Default">
<input readonly value="Readonly" id="rd">
```

AND THE CSS-->

```
#rd
{
cursor:text;
}
```

That should do it... if that's what you want.

Comment: The mouse cursor isn't the problem, it's the I-beam that's supposed to show up between the letters. As far as I can tell there's no corresponding "text-cursor" CSS property.

Comment: The cursor property I showed above is not just the "text-cursor" property, but for every element existing.